# How to erase a circle?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I would like to erase a circle from an area in the canvas.

I see the [clearRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) function, but obviously there's no *clearCircle()* function, so how should I proceed?

Exactly what I'm trying to do is:

- Draw a black rectangle
- Cut a circular hole in the middle

```js
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 0;
context.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);

// Now cut a circle in the middle...
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150">
```

Comment: Can you provide some code or provide a jsfiddle please. Also this does depend on if something is drawn behind it and it doesn't need to be erased and etc.

Comment: @Canvas Writing you a fiddle now, but it will be very simple because there are no other criterai

Comment: @Drahcir This is basically a clearRect but using a circle https://jsfiddle.net/9L2t4ar4/

Comment: @Canvas Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sn9ge47s/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
```

is the key (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing)).

> The existing content is kept where it doesn't overlap the new shape.

This demo defines a background color to the HTML `body` to demonstrate that the circle is actually transparent:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('ca').getContext('2d');

// Draw rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#5f6';
c.fillRect(10, 10, 180, 180);

// Set global composite operation to destination-out
c.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

// Draw circle
c.strokeStyle = "#000";
c.beginPath();
c.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI*2);
c.fill();
```

```css
body {
  background: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="ca" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just fill the circle white? Example

```
  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  context.fill();
```

Comment: Because it wont be transparent

Comment: Oh. What do you mean by transparent?

Comment: Transparent is "clear" or "see-through"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sqaure with a circle in the middle

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9L2t4ar4/1/

javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var clearCircle = function (xPos, yPos, Radius) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(xPos, yPos, Radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = '#000';
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
}

clearCircle(200, 200, 150);
```

You don't have to make a function, I just made it a function because it seemed you wanted a `clearRect()` but using a circle, so `clearCircle()` seems appropriate

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't erase a circle, it draws one. I need an empty area.

Comment: @Drahcir That is an empty area, basically what you have to remember is the canvas is as canvas, so you have to think about layers, you draw the last thing first I.E. a background, you then draw your foreground items last, so they don't get overridden by the background. so when you want to erase a circle from the canvas, you have to overlay a circle to technically erase what has been drawn.

Comment: Actually I'm using PIXI.js, I was going to create my canvas as described, then generate a PIXI.Texture from it and use within my game - The canvas would have contained one frame for an animation.

Comment: You didn't state this in your tags :( I have just edited your question to add the PIXI.js tag, also you can just change the circle colour to be equal to your webpage colour to give the illusion of a hole in your canvas